# Change the name when Customizing CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I customize the campaign form and i face the some problem[image]

1.How to customize the name "GENERAL".i need the name instead of GENERAL .Where to change?or which property should i change?

2.cant delete Lock symbol  fields if we try ,  its saying "It is allowed only for business units".How to unlock and How to delete this?

Comment: what if you can just recreated this field I don't see any problems with that

Answer (score 2):

As Guido suggests, double you can edit the name of the tab by opening up the form in the form editor, double clicking on the tab, and changing the label.

As far as the locked field, you'll have to mark the field as not required, in the entity customization, publish your changes, then you can delete the field from the form.

Answer (score 1):

The label for any tab can be changed by the form editor, if you want a dynamic value you can set using supported customization as this example:

```js
var firstTab = Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(0);
firstTab.setLabel("new tab name");
```

If a field is locked, it means that is business required (in your case is the name of the campaign that must be filled), you can always hide the field and pre-fill the value using javascript code inside onload, onchange or onsave events.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone else can suggest a better (i.e. supported) solution but until then - why not find out the id of those elements and edit them directly from JS in *onload*? Let me repeat, though, that such an operation **is unsupported**.